# NPM Package local VS global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webserver

I've been having some issues with node, npm and trying to figure out the package structure, and I'm not very sure what to Google. I've been trying to find a common convention when it comes to how npm packages are imported.

I've recently been writing a small web server in Node, and I've been using [HttpDispatcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpdispatcher) to help take care of requests. The problem comes in when I attempt to make more than one HttpDispatcher 'object.' When I do, it doesn't actually create a new one, and instead continues to use the first one I create.

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Node in general, however I have run into issues in the past where creating anonymous functions (I think that's what they're called) within a loop does not always, if at all, do as intended. Thus, I'm really curious how packages that are meant to have multiple instances are generally used?

I fixed my problem by making the HttpDispatcher 'object' global (removing the *var* keyword in front. This will actually create a new object as expected. I'm worried that this is not proper, though.

So I'm asking you:
**What is the proper way to declare/initialize/export objects that are declared in an npm package?** Should I submit a pull request or suggestion to the author of this package with my issues?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you should contact the author of the HttpDispatcher module

At the end of the HttpDispatchermodule, instead of exporting an instance :

```
module.exports = new HttpDispatcher();
```

The author could export the constructor itself, and then you could make as many instances as you need in consumer modules :

```
module.exports = HttpDispatcher;
```

Comment: Just to expand on why this is (you beat me to the punch with this answer :p) - once you've imported something once in Node, the instance gets cached, so subsequent imports will return the same object. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I ultimately ended up doing in the first place, I just wasn't sure what the 'standard' was for exporting modules. Thanks for the help!